# Pytest: Define custom path for tests collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Im building a test runner package, with custom fixtures, pytest.ini and conftest.
I want this runner to be able to accept as parameter a directory path, 
and collect the tests in that path and run them using my custom configuration files.

What Im doing now is copying the given directory to a known location (tests) inside my package and then run pytest programmatically with path to the tests and --rootdir params.

```
Dir tree:
- runner
---- tests
---- conftest.py
---- pytest.ini
---- fixtures.py
---- runner.py

Python code:
pytest_params = ['tests', '--rootdir=runner', <other params passed to pytest>]
pytest.main([pytest_params])
```

Which works great.
But I dont want to copy the entire tests dir for every run.

Ive tried to set `testpaths` arg in pytest.ini and remote the path argument from pytest params, but this causes pytest to lose rootdir and pytest.ini files and of course fail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly specify the location of ini file. You can use `-c` argument to specify the location of your ini file. To load settings from runner directory, you need to run `conftest.py` with pytest.

You argument would look like this:

```
pytest_params = ['conftest.py', '-c=pytest.ini', '--rootdir=<path_of_external_tests', <other params passed to pytest>]
pytest.main(pytest_params)
```

Comment: Thanks @SilentGuy, but now, when specifying the conftest.py, pytest doesnt find any tests. When I remove conftest.py param, only then pytest finds the tests in rootdir. Any ideas ?

Comment: Addition: Apparently when conftest is specified, pytest ignores the --rootdir and looks for tests in the same directory where conftest is :/

Comment: One workaround could be to symlink your conftest file at the top of runner dir in python script. This way pytest would collect all the tests as if the conftest.py was there. But you can't have more than one conftest.py in a dir.

Comment: I've tried to symlink all tests to a known directory, but this causes all kinds of issues with conftest :/

Comment: Other workaround is to define rootdir as the common top directory of your conftest and the test dir. And, specify the test collection inclusion list as your conftest and the test dir. e.g. test path: a/b/c/tests and conftest a/d/x/conftest.py. specify `a` as root dir and specify `a/b/c/tests` and `a/d/x/` as `--collect-only`. This is the hacky way. 

Non hacky way is to package your configuration in a pytest plugin. And install that plugin to use the configuration wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! Ive eventually went with Creating links to the test files instead of copying them all.