# How to pass "-c" argument correctly to pytest.main?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933832/pytest-define-custom-path-for-tests-collection) but couldn't fix the error.

I am designing a testing framework based on using `pytest`.

`pytest` will be called in a python script and not from the command line.

I have several directories in each of which there are:

- a file called `tests.py` in which `test_` functions are placed.
- a `.ini` file

What I am trying to do is to store each testing report in its corresponding directory. That is the why I am using a separate `.ini` file in each directory.

Following is the content of each `.ini` file:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --html=<path>/test_report.html
```

And the whole setup is:

```
root
+-- dir_1
|   +-- d1.ini
|   +-- tests_d1.py
+-- dir_2
|   +-- d2.ini
|   +-- tests_d2.py
.
.
.
+-- dir_n
|   +-- dn.ini
|   +-- tests_dn.py
```

When calling `pytest.main`, I do it as follows:

```
pytest_params = ['-v', <path> + tests.py,
                 '-c', <path> + <some name>.ini]

pytest.main(pytest_params)
```

But when I run `pytest.main` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: usage: main.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --html=<path>/test_report.html <path>/tests.py 
  inifile: <path>/<some name>.ini
  rootdir: <path>
```

(I removed the paths from the error message).

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ronny Pfannschmidt answered my question on GitHub:

1. `pytest-html` has to be installed.
2. `__init__.py` files are required to be added in each directory or the `importlib` has to be used.

This is [the original answer](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/discussions/10861#discussioncomment-5514922) on GitHub.